# Questions using QuickBlox JavaScript SDK

Tags: javascript, php, quickblox

I'm new to QuickBlox and have a couple of questions. I've tried searching through StackOverflow and elsewhere but seems there are no answers to my questions. 
I could very well have missed something in the QuickBlox documentation (or not aware of something in regards to JavaScript).

This relates to the JavaScript SDK as I will be using that to implement the chat feature. The idea is to add a chat feature to a web app built with Laravel.

My first question relates to the initialisation/authorisation. It seems very insecure to have your QuickBlox auth keys in a JavaScript file, as the file can be easily viewed through the browser's View Source option. 
How would you hide this sensitive information??

With that in mind, I've looked into doing it using PHP. Using the sample code from the documentation I can get the session token successfully. I then got a copy of the chat app from the SDK and have been trying to integrate the PHP code into that, so that instead of using the config.js it uses my php to get the token and pass that into QB.init. But it seems that does not work.
The chat app just sits there. Looking at the JS debugger in Firebug it seems an exception is being thrown: Cannot create a new session without app credentials. Which puzzles me as I'm getting that through PHP? Why would it fail on the JavaScript side?

Thanks.

Comment: Looking into the error, from what I can see, this exception is happening when you click on a user (the sample app has user Quick and user Blox, I've changed the user details to use 2 users I've set up in my account). So on clicking the first user it tries to login that user and I think that is where the exception is coming from.

Answer (score 1):

Wonderful!  I already submitted this as an issue to them:

https://github.com/QuickBlox/quickblox-javascript-sdk/issues/72

Do the following to resolve your issue (it's a workaround):

```
QB.init(token, false, false, QBConfig);
QB.service.getSession().application_id = your_app_id;
```

And.. I have an idea for a PR but really the workaround will do for now.

EDIT:

Try the following...

```
var QBConfig = {
    chatProtocol: {
        active: 2
    },
    debug: !true,
    webrtc: {
        answerTimeInterval: 30,
        dialingTimeInterval: 5
    },
    creds: {
        appId: YOUR_APP_ID
    }
};

QB.init(token, false, false, QBConfig);
QB.service.getSession().application_id = your_app_id; // probably still need this too
```

Now try this (assuming you're using the original JS from the sample):

```
function createSession() {
  //QB.createSession(caller, function(err, res) {
    //if (res) {
      connectChat();
   // }
  //});
}
```

Comment: I assume QBConfig is just an array with other options etc? 
I've put the code in, but still get the exception.

Comment: correct -- I can take a look at this later today.  Their JS SDK is less popular than their Android one so there is a few more quirks that you'll run into..

Comment: and.. you're using the latest release? 1.17?

Comment: Just grabbed 1.17. Tried again, same exception.

Comment: So... now I know why you get your error and why I don't receive the same exception .. I do all the createSession stuff via the REST API and don't call createSession via the JS SDK but I still run into an issue later on which is why I use the workaround I posted.  I don't believe you can do a workaround without modified the SDK.  Refer to my edit for a suggestion...

Comment: Please let me know if it work since I can't easily test in my current setup.. thanks.

Comment: creds.appId is the configuration setting for your appId... that is how it is stored internally.  you may need to do QBConfig.creds = {appId: your_app_id};

Comment: Still not working. I'm just going to go back to the usual key/secret method for now. With regards to hiding the javascript config info, how would you go about doing that, so that people can't see the app id, key and secret key?

Comment: I do all the create session work via the REST API and use the workaround I mentioned.

Comment: did you include both the workarounds that I mention in the post?  You'll likely need both to get it working.

Comment: Actually... I think I just realized what your problem is -- you shouldn't need to call createSession in the JS SDK if you are creating the token via the REST API.

Comment: I'm still getting the exception _Cannot create a new session without app credentials (app ID, auth key and auth secret)_

Comment: You do not want to call QB.createSession() anywhere in your code because you should be calling the REST API to do the create session for you.  The exception you are experiencing is because you are calling QB.createSession().  You have already created a session because you have your token, so if you call QB.createSession it'll error out.  Does that help/make sense?

Comment: I think I found where it might be getting called again, but I'm not sure how to change. In the sample chat from the SDK, it's in the connection.js file

Comment: Ooh hang on, I think I got it!

Comment: please accept my answer if you've got it working.. thanks!

Comment: It connects, but messages don't come through properly

Comment: you'll also need to do this workaround if you don't have it in there still `QB.service.getSession().application_id = your_app_id;`

Comment: Now it's not working anymore. Thanks for your help, I'm just going to go back to the old way.

Answer (score 1):

You are right with the PHP add-on. It can help you to secure your QB credentials.

Other solution is to build custom script which will build your credentials,
something like obfuscation logic. And then minify this script to hide all logic details.

Anyway, if you decided to use **QB.init("token")** then you don't need to use **QB.createSession** at all. The **QB.init("token")** is used to bypass the **QB.createSession**  call.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript SDK 1.17.1 release

http://quickblox.com/developers/Javascript#Framework_changelog

Now you can initialise the SDK with the session token and application ID:

```
QB.init('1b785b603a9ae88d9dfbd1fc0cca0335086927f1', 3451);
```

Answer (score 0):

The following steps worked for me after struggling with the same issue:

1. From my Javscript file, I use ajax call to get the AppId and Token from PHP/Server-Side class, using the doc at: `https://docs.quickblox.com/reference/authentication#create-session` more specifically creating a User Session
2. Once I receive the result from Quickblox, I output the result back to the Javascript and set an AppId, Token and UserId variable in javascript:
   `var qb_app_id = 12333; var qb_token = "ABC123"; var qb_user_id = 1234567;`
3. Then I call `QB.init(qb_app_id , qb_token , null, quickblox_config);`
4. Finally, I use the following without any error:

```html
QB.chat.connect({userId: qb_user_id, password: qb_token, resource: 'practdashboard'}, function (err, roster) {
        if (err) {
            return;
        }
    });
```

See here:
https://quickblox.com/developers/Web_XMPP_Chat_Sample#Guide:_Getting_Started_with_Chat_API and refer specifically to **Custom resource**